# orderby in WP_QUERY - Use the order from the Dashboard

Tags: wp-query, query, order

I'm using the **[Anything Order Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/anything-order/)** to order custom post types in my dashboard.

For a `wp_query`, I'd like the output to order the posts in the same order as I have them in the dashboard.

What would I use for the "orderby" parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out.

`'order' => 'ASC'` (or `DESC` - however you'd like) and `'orderby' => 'menu_order'` solves this.